# java was started but returned exit code = -805306369

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins, helios

Can anyone help me with this error:

> java was started but returned exit code = -805306369
>   C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe
>   -jar C:\Program Files\Java\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.11.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

Comment: Related? http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/171902/

Comment: Google: http://www.google.de/search?q=java+was+started+but+returned+exit+code+%3D+-805306369
One possible hint: http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

Answer (score 25):

Just had this issue, for me it was a corrupted workspace osgi cache. The solution was to  run eclipse with the `-clean` parameter as

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

After some time, eclipse required to clean up, the workspace selection dialog popped up and I could start eclipse normally again.

The `-clean` parameter is documented [in the eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)

Comment: This helped with IBM Rational Application Developer also. Thank you.

Comment: This works very well.  Initially ran the command from the command line after that it runs perfectly from the normal desktop shortcut

Answer (score 14):

My problem was a corrupted workspace the solution was from Rob's link:

http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

Comment: Reinstalling eclipse solved my problem. Workspace switching was not enough

Comment: Provide a summary or content in your answer, link only answers will not be useful once the link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

I started getting the same error "exit code = -805306369" just out of no where.

Eventually I looked at the Eclipse logs at the `<workspace_directory>/.metadata/.log` and realized that my Source Control plugin (Perforce in my case) was unable to connect and the eclipse was stuck.

This was because my eclipse was piggy back(depending) on the client connection that I have with my Perforce windows client and my Perforce client was not connected to the server. I connected my Perforce client and the eclipse started working normal.

Answer (score 4):

this happens when mostly workspace is corrupted..... cooler solution is just to switch the workspace to safer location(new location).... and just import the project from previous workspace... princess can still be saved....

Answer (score 3):

For me , Just change your Workspace to another one

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, when workspace already setted up. Since the java virtual machine cannot be created. try command: *java -version*

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I restarted my machine, and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the class file in my project was corrupted. The name of a class file was too long and I was not able to delete or rename it, so I rename the folder containing it and then I was able to delete the project and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now i know that my workspace was corrupted, it solved my problem.

1. Go to your workspace and rename it.
2. Start your eclipse and by default it will create a workspace.
3. Go to `File` -> `Switch Workspace`, choose your original workspace.

Comment: If it's in Netbeans IDE, what the solution i take to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to disable "Automatically find new updates and notify me."  The option was not there on the Install/Updates page.  Perhaps eclipse workbench has changed since that answer was written.

However, running eclipse with the -clean option in my old workspace did the trick for me.  The way to do that in windows is to first find the directory where eclipse.exe lives.  You can go to the start menu and in the "search menus and files" bar, type eclipse.  You should see the purple globe icon pop up under "Programs."  Hover your mouse over it and it will tell you the directory it exists in.

Then... open "computer" or some other window from the start menu and from there navigate to the window where eclipse is.  Click your mouse in the bar at the top where the directory is displayed (somewhere not on the text).  That directory will highlight. Now type cmd.  A black command window will open and you will be in the directory where eclipse is.  At the command prompt (drum roll) type eclipse.exe -clean

eclipse will start.  Make sure it is asking to go to your corrupted workspace and click OK.
Wait for it and soon you will know if your workspace has been uncorrupted.  Yay!

Answer (score 1):

“java was started but returned exit code = -805306369” caused by Eclipse´s currupted workspace, I solved my problem with this 4 steps:

1) claose the eclipse.

2) Kill the adb from task manager.

3) Start your eclipse and by default it will create a workspace or start with new workspace.

4) Go to File -> Switch Workspace, choose your original workspace.

Comment: what is "the adb"?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is a work laptop, so pretty secure SOE
64 bit Win 7.

- Unzipped Eclipse MARS onto a folder on "C" drive
- Install failed consistently with  Java error code -`805306369`
- Created a separate folder on 'C' drive for workspace, granted
  everyone full-control and that fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue when opening files using shortcut - Ctrl+Shift+R.
I got it resolved by disabling "Automatic Updates". 
Steps to disable automatic update in eclipse (helios): Windows >> Preference >> Install/Update >> Automatic Updates. Disable "Automatically find new updates and notify me".

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to get mine working. I used a combination of the solutions above. It works for me.

---

> Step 1: Change your workspace to some other names e.g. change it from workspace to workspace1.
>
> Step 2: Access your eclipse and stop automatic updates (provided that you could access after changing your workspace)
>
> Step 3: Exit your eclipse with workspace1
>
> Step 4: Start your eclipse with former workspace by entering eclipse.exe -clean (if you are using others then use e.g. MuleStudio.exe -clean)

---

> In conclusion, using a combination of solutions such as changing workspace, stop automatic updates and -clean work for me. Try it yourself.