# Eclipse Crash "java was started but returned exit code = -805306369"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm aware there is an identical post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369) but none of the proposed solutions have changed anything and they are quite old (problems to do with Java6) and seem to be referring to a bug to do with Eclipse.

My problem is when I am developing in [Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junosr1); either making changes to java files or changing dependencies etc, Eclipse randomly hangs and then freezes. I have to force close eclipse and I get this message

[image: Eclipse RCP Error Message]

Things I have tried so far:

- Restarted eclipse and PC
- Added the `-clean` command to the very beginning of the eclipse.ini file
- Created a brand new work space and attempted to develop in that

I'm running on the latest version of Java (1.7.0_13) and haven't got a clue what to do next.

The problem has happened 4 or 5 times in a number of different occasions:

- When I have tried to add a new package to the src folder
- When I have tried to add a class to a package in the src folder
- When I have tried to edit a class in a package in the src folder
- When using Ctrl+Space in a class in the src folder

Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated! Need to get this problem sorted so I can get developing for my 3rd Year University Project :)

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/RJKZIqX.png) is a link to the .log file if it helps. This crash happened in a brand new work space after I tried to add a new package to the src folder

Comment: You cant use 64bit if you dont have a 64bit OS. ;D

Comment: But I do have a 64 bit OS :/. What made you come to that conclusion Peter? Was it something in the Log file? Just wondering so I can investigate it further :)

Comment: You force to use win32-dll's by "-os win32", so the java guess he should use native 32bit-dll's.

Comment: So should I get a 32bit version of Java and tell Eclipse RCP to compile using that by changing the eclipse.ini file?

Comment: You better get rid of -os and -ws.

Comment: I assumed you meant in the eclipse.ini file however there isn't -os and -ws in there to delete. So could you elaborate on where I need to delete these so I can see if it helps :)

Comment: Hm, wired, i see -os and -ws in the hardcopy you posted. I guess you edit the eclipse.ini using the wrong user. So: is the owner of the eclipse.exe the same as the owner of the eclipse.ini?

Comment: Yes it was Peter. I seem to have fixed the problem now with a big clear out of old versions of Java and fresh installs of both Java and Eclipse. I had done fresh installs a few times before but this time it seemed to have fix it. Hopefully it is not a temporary fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of researching and filing bug reports to no avail I tried one last clear out of Java and fresh installs of Eclipse to try and fix the error and it seems to have worked.

Here is what I did:

- Un-installed Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers
- Un-installed Java from my PC and deleted any old Java folders that were left behind (I didn't do this in previous clear outs so maybe there was an old version of Java messing something up)
- Did a fresh install of Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers and a fresh install of the latest Java
- I also deleted my old PATH variable for Java in Environment Variables and put the new one at the front of all the other entries

This seems to have fixed the error for now so hopefully it won't be a short term fix

Comment: instead of doing so many things you would have change the workspace.that might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @javadoc. Did that. And then: a) closed Eclipse b) removed the created virgin workspace and put the original one back c) also added '-clean' to eclipse.ini. And... Eclipse boots back just like it did last week. Don't know if the folder exercise or the '-clean' was what saved me. Thanks for your hint, anyways!

Comment: Had the same problem fixed it with the update of eclipse, without reinstalling

Answer (score 3):

> java was started but returned exit code = -805306369

is caused by Eclipse´s corrupted workspace, I solved my problem with these 3 steps:

#### 1) Go to your workspace and rename it.

#### 2) Start your eclipse and by default it will create a workspace.

#### 3) Go to File -> Switch Workspace, choose your original workspace.

Comment: Thanks, @Elenasys that worked and was easier than uninstalling.

Comment: you´re wellcome, uninstalling never will be an option! =)

Comment: My original workspace still caused the hang and error when I switched back, but this did get me a working Eclipse from which I could rebuild (and back up!) my workspace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I opened another instance of eclipse and it prompted me to choose a new workspace. I did so and there it was resolved. Then I closed the new workspace and resorted back to old workspace as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If using Maven projects, check pom.xml, this may corrupted. Mine resolved by fixing pom file.

Answer (score -1):

`java was started but returned exit code = -805306369` caused by Eclipse´s currupted workspace, I solved my problem with this 4 steps:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Kill the adb from task manager.
3. Start Eclipse and by default it will create a workspace or start with new workspace.
4. Go to File -> Switch Workspace, choose your original workspace.

Comment: I tried this today with Eclipse Mars and apparently killing adb, even after Eclipse has been closed, corrupted a file, so now I can't restart Eclipse; I get the dreaded "Java was started but returned exit code=13" message.