# Eclipse is throwing error - Java was started but returned exit code= -805306369

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am trying to run an application in Eclipse, it is getting hung and after 15 mins the following error is displayed.
I am working on Eclipse from past 2 months and till now it was working fine. I am using Eclipse Indigo.

[image: Error]

Comment: I would try to isolate the problem to know if it is something related to the code or the environment. Try running the app in a different computer and / or application server.

Comment: What were your last changes on your app  ?

Comment: This might help: [Eclipse Crash “java was started but returned exit code = -805306369”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803836/eclipse-crash-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369)

Comment: Is there an Eclipse launcher log in the configuration folder of your Eclipse installation (e.g., eclipse/configuration/123999.log)? If so its content would be helpful.

Comment: @code4jhon - There was no much changes in the code.. I just added few more functionality. I dont think it might be a problem.

Comment: @s106mo - I don't find any log files in configuration sub folder. I think re installing will be the only option left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java was started but returned exit code = -805306369](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369)

Answer (score 2):

JUST DELETE WORKSPACE(S)
I had the same problem and its easily solved by deleting the my Workspace folders, in Eclipse --> File --> Switch Workspace  ,I found the location of my Workspaces and I went to the direction and deleted them, after I did this my problem solved :)

Comment: instead of deleting the workspaces, see this solution: http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

Answer (score 0):

Ways to Isolate and fix the error

1. Try running other apps to see if the error is persistent among all
   apps.
2. Try reinstalling (repairing) the latest version of java
3. Try performing a fresh install of java
4. Try re-downloading eclipse

Comment: I started getting this error after I updated my code and I think I will revert it and check ...

Answer (score 0):

You may check out the `eclipse.ini` file. From [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

> 1. Each option and each argument to an option must be on its own line.
> 2. All lines after -vmargs are passed as arguments to the JVM, so all arguments and options for eclipse must be specified before -vmargs
>      (just like when you use arguments on the command-line)
> 3. Any use of -vmargs on the command-line replaces all -vmargs settings in the .ini file unless --launcher.appendVmargs is specified
>      either in the .ini file or on the command-line. (doc)

Also the reason for the error may be that you are attempting to start Eclipse using the wrong version of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). If that is the case  you may use this to start eclipse with hardcoded 64-bit JVM:

```
eclipse -vm C:/java/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Also check [Eclipse Crash “java was started but returned exit code = -805306369”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803836/eclipse-crash-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369)

Comment: I dont think I am using wrong version since it has worked from past 2 months but still I will cross check it ...

Comment: @SDM:- I have just edited my answer with the a similar question Thread. Hope that resolved your query!

Answer (score 0):

Trying starting Eclipse with a different 64 bit JVM. To do so:

```
eclipse.exe -vm c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

If this works update the first two lines in your `eclipse.ini` file to the following:

```
-vm
c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue where my application cannot be debugged in eclipse. Solution that worked for me :

> **Open the debug view and remove some breakpoints** ( such as some
>   remaining on NullPointersExceptions or ArrayOutOfBound exceptions)

It doesn't hang any longer.

Hope it helps :)