# Eclipse Kepler not responding on load

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I searched a bit through the net but couldn't find any solution. I am trying to start my eclipse and it stuck in this stage:
[image]

Then when I terminate it through Task Manager I get this:

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: c:\windows\system32\javaw.exe? huh... I think something is wrong with your JVM installation.

Answer (score 3):

First step is to check for a corrupt work-space.  Please refer to this awesome article on the [Java Exit Code -805306369](http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html).  Essentially try re-naming your `work-space` so `Eclipse` opens without using it to see if it loads up.

If it does load up then you can import your projects into the new "un-corrupted" work-space.

---

If that wasn't the issue then it's possible that `Eclipse` is attempting to use the wrong `javaw` executable.

Try to specify the path by right clicking on `Eclipse` shortcut, properties, in target field enter:

```
"C:\<Eclipse Path>" -vm "C:\<Path to javaw>"
```

For `<Eclipse Path>` enter the path to your `Eclipse` program.  Example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe`.

For `<Path to javaw>` enter the path to your `javaw` executable.  Example: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin`.

This should specify which `javaw` to use, if it works then it will confirm that your `Eclipse` is using a different one.

---

*Side Note:*  I'm not sure if you're aware - but for things like this surrounding the `-805306369` with `""` in `Google` will make sure it finds pages with that exact string in them.  Very useful so you don't get thousands of pages on other Java exit codes.  Hope it helps!

---

Comment: Thank you but I installed a new eclipse, created a new workspace and the problem persists even in this case..

Comment: @AlbanoVito For sanity check can you please confirm that these steps didn't change anything? - After you installed a new Eclipse you weren't able to successfully open at all?  So the first time you went to open, after it prompted for work-space name, it gave the same error?

Comment: Yes you are right, it freeze again. It asked for a workspace initially, then it stuck in the same way. I am thinking that it may be a problem with JDK but I just re-installed it and nothing changed..

Comment: I have made several restarts till now :(

Comment: @AlbanoVito Please check out this other SO post/answer and see if it solves your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923650/2459730.

Comment: Practically I have done that too.. However I will try removing everything related.. Thank you