# ..Java was started but returned exit code- 805306369

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

I have checked everywhere for answers but can't seem to find anything relating my problem. Eclipse launches fine, but it does not show any sort of menu bar. Not exactly sure how to fix this problem. I tried to link photos indicating the exact problem but was told I need a reputation of 10.....

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369

Comment: What os? What version of Java? What version of eclipse? Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: I am currently using Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U45, Eclipse Kepler. Just recently started happening after updates and installs this morning. Was working fine, finished off my android app, then did the installs. The Eclipse program opens up completely, can view everything. Just no available tool bar for file, menu, etc to allow me to choose a project and what not. I don't see this Error until I close the program, program can not be closed by a simple click on the ESC in the right hand corner. I then need to access the Task Manager to end the program. That is when I see the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the authors real issue. It is only shown after he forcefully killed Eclipse.