# Eclipse Hangs Up and Crashes with Exit Code -805306369

Tags: java, eclipse, web

[image]

I really have no idea whats wrong here. Whenever I create a new project, it just hangs and exits with code -805306369. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a 32-bit JRE with a 64-bit eclipse?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : Thanks.. I downloaded the 32 bit Eclipse version and it seems to be working fine now...