# my STS cannot running

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

[image]

when I click , become the program is "not responding"
when I click again, it shows the following error "java platform"
I am using `STS 3.1.0'

Shoul I uninstall and install again?

I think my Window is damaged..

But yersterday it was not like this, I dont know why today it is.

[image]

this is the log

[image]

anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Have you looked in the logfiles?

Comment: Have you upgraded Java ? There is eclipse.ini file ?

Comment: @TomJonckheere i already upload the log..

Comment: @MrPhi where can i find the eclipse.ini?yes last month i update java

Comment: i'm usins STS (Spring tool Suite) ..i found STS.ini at folder springsouce..

Comment: at STS.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: If you do not know what is eclipse/sts.ini please read about it and if you setup more Megabytes on XXMaxPermSize maybe help you.

Comment: @MrPhi 
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar --launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807 -product org.springsource.sts.ide --launcher.defaultAction openFile --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false -Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Comment: @MrPhi that i copied from file STS.ini

Comment: "XXMaxPermSize 256M" change 256 on eg. 512

Comment: @MrPhi like this "XX:MaxPermSize=256 on eg. 512" ?

Comment: exactly like there is in your properties file

Comment: @MrPhi when i changed to 256 or 512..it cannot running

Comment: Solution should be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369

Comment: my java  -version is 1.7.0_45

Comment: problem solved, i change this -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 to 1.7 .. but in enviroment java_home i set 1.7

Comment: i dont know why i cannot access last folder workspace..it say "already use another program"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am just delete folder ".metadata" from default destination folder  and its working like befor