# JBoss Developer Studio crash when save the VDB

Tags: jboss, data-visualization, teiid

When i create a VDB, change the JNDI name then save the VDB, my JBoss Developer Studio become crash and show the following message:

[image]

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you provide version of JBDS you have?

Comment: 8.1.0 GA
By the way, i solve the problem by reinstall my JBDS

Comment: [See identical Stackoverflow issue for Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369).
It turns out that the IDE-workspace has become corrupted when you receive the error code `-805306369`. Delete your workspace, create a completely new workspace and reimport your project. You can consider using a different IDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java was started but returned exit code = -805306369](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157794/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369)